# htaccess : Redirect all url to index.php in public folder exept api folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this tree structure in my php app :

```
/
├─ app/
│  ├─ models/
│  ├─ views/
│  ├─ controllers/
│  ├─ core/
├─ public/
│  ├─ index.php
│  ├─ js/
│  ├─ css/
├─ api/
```

And i want to use htaccess file to redirect all the urls even if the url is wrong to the file `index.php` existing in public folder.
But i want to except api folder from this redirection and i want it to became accessible with a direct url.
One more thing, i like to delete the public from url :
`http://localhost/public/controller/method` to `http://localhost/controller/action`

Comment: I believe it helps - https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-

Comment: Sounds straight forward, you want to implement an internal rewriting rule and add a condition to exclude the api folder. You will find lots of examples here on SO for that, you also definitely should take a look into the documentation of the apache rewriting module. As typical for OpenSource software projects it is of excellent quality and comes with great examples.

Comment: So you should start out yourself, implement what you require. If you made an attempt which does not work as you'd expect and if you fail to understand the issue, _then_ is the time to come here and ask for help. FOr which you need to add your current implementation to the question.

Comment: @arkascha i googled this question for two days and i don't found any examples that answer to my question.
if you have some samples or dowloaded examples. Please help me

Comment: @EdrianBiagi i saw this link before but i can't apply it. I don't understand how htaccess works

Comment: As said this site already contains many examples for what you ask. Sure, you will need to adapt those to meet your precise needs, but that is how one learns... A simple search reveals lots of such questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rewrite+public+folder+